# Using Swagger 2 in Spring 6 project throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox, jakarta-migration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCJPl.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUinu.png)

I am trying to implement **SWAGGER2** in my Spring Project. But while I use **@EnableSwagger2 **annotation it returns this-> Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.**
What's the reason here??

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post your code as text and use the `{ }` button to format it as code.

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Getting-started

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem, you need some changes in your pom.xml file.

1.reduce your spring version from 3...  to 2.7.2 .

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

2. run the code if you get error then you need to reduce your  java version also.

   11

hope these steps helps you to resolve the issue.
Thankyou.

Comment: Yup. You are right. In order to implement swagger2 in spring the spring version must above 3.